# Bootstrap Dialog - How do I stop it closing automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-dialog

I am using a Ajax to call a MVC controller to submit a form, on a successful call I want to display a dialog box, currently its working the way I want to but the box opens for about a second then closes.

```
$("#addBtn").click(function () {
    $(".container form").ajaxSubmit({ url: '/umbraco/Surface/Basket/AddNow', type: 'post', success: function () { afterSuccess(); } })
});

function afterSuccess() {
    BootstrapDialog.alert('Test');
}
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: where is your dialog declared here?

Comment: @user2537315 are you loading modal using `data-toggle` attribute or  using custom JavaScript?

Comment: Isn't this simply because you create an ad-hoc (on the stack) dialog and when the method ends this terminates (and auto closes)?

Comment: @mdxs maybe but this seems to work... its where I got the code from http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/

Comment: Why has this question been voted down?

Comment: Can you perhaps provide a JSFiddle showing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in the Java Script, the problem was in the html of the page. I moved the submit button out side of the form.

This must happen quite a lot! - Hope this helps some else.